Squid proxy configuration file: Correct I guess but not working
I've configured a Squid proxy server on my desktop, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to it from another device on the same network. The proxy server is set up to utilize a 4G modem connected to the desktop.
However, when attempting to connect to the proxy server from the other device, web pages fail to load.
Would anyone be able to offer assistance or suggestions to resolve this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
# Squid Configuration File

# Set the port for incoming connections
http_port 3128

# Define ACLs (Access Control Lists) for each port
acl port_3128 myport 3128

# Define the outgoing address for the 4G LTE modem interface
tcp_outgoing_address 195.203.225.137 port_3128

# Allow access only from localhost
http_access allow localhost

# Deny access to anyone else
http_access deny all

PS :my proxy server works fine without the 4G modem, but as soon as I implement ACLs and tcp_outgoing_address, everything stops working.
